# Not able to bring ad-hoc connection up

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, adhoc

I am trying to set up an ad-hoc connection with another linux system on my ubuntu 20.04 laptop. I have managed to do this yesterday but for some reason I am not able to do it now.

I have followed the command line instructions from here:
 [WifiDocs/Adhoc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Adhoc)

But when i try to bring the interface back up with

```
sudo ip link set wlp1s0 up
```

I get

```
RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy
```

I've looked at every discussion I could find, most suggest to stop `network-manager`, which I did following the wiki, so it does not solve the problem.

`dsmeg -w`  does not show any error.